# What is the fraction field of $A[z]/(z^2-f)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Suppose $A$ is an integrally closed domain and that $f\in A$ has no repeated prime factors. Then $z^2-f$ is irreducible and $B:=A[z]/(z^2-f)$ is an integral domain. I am trying to see why $K(B)$, the fraction field of $B$, is $K(A)[z]/(z^2-f)$.

In $K(B)$, we are inverting all elements of $B$ that are not contained in the ideal $(z^2-f)$. So then I think this should give us $K(B)=(A[z]-(z^2-f))^{-1}B$.

Is this correct? And if so, why are the two forms of $K(B)$ equal?

Comment: One way to look at it is to think of $B = A[z]/(z^2-f)$ as $A[\sqrt{f}]$, so this is $A$ to which you add a square root of $f$. The fraction field of $B$ must contain the inverses of elements of $A$ (so it contains $K(A)$) so it contains $K(A)[\sqrt{f}]$. And $K(A)[\sqrt{f}]$ is actually a field : if $a_1 + a_2 \sqrt{f} \in K(A)[\sqrt{f}]$, then $\frac{1}{a_1 + a_2 \sqrt{f}} = \frac{a_1 - a_2 \sqrt{f}}{(a_1 + a_2 \sqrt{f})(a_1 - a_2 \sqrt{f})} =  \frac{a_1}{a_1^2 - f a_2^2} - \frac{a_2}{a_1^2 - f a_2^2} \sqrt{f} \in K(A)[\sqrt{f}]$.

Comment: @JoelCohen So $K(B)$ contains $K(A)[\sqrt{f}]$, which is a field. But does this imply that they are equal?

Comment: @ponchan : the fraction field of a ring $B$ is the smallest field that contains $B$, so any field $F$ such that $B \subset F \subset K(B)$ is $K(B)$ itself.